# kaprekar number calculation fails for more than two digits

Tags: c

why is the code not working? i cant get a valid output. Please help me to find whether the input is a Kaprekar number or not.I think i made it too complicated. Any suggestions for a simple method??

For example:

- 9 is a Kaprekar number since 9² = 81 & 8+1=9.
- 297 is a Kaprekar number since 297² = 88209 & 88+209 = 297. Below is the code.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, a, temp, length, sum = 0, s, i, rem, temp1, length1, sum1[10], sum2[10];

    printf("n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    a = n * n;
    printf("%d\n", a);

    temp = a;
    length = 0;

    while (temp > 0) {    
        length++;
        temp = temp / 10;    
    }

    temp1 = n;
    length1 = 0;

    while (temp1 > 0) {    
        length1++;
        temp1 = temp1 / 10;    
    }

    if (length1 == 1) {    
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {        
            rem = a % 10;
            sum = sum + rem;
            a = a / 10;
        }
        if (sum == n) {        
            printf("Kaprekar number");
        } else {        
            printf("not a kaprekar number");        
        }    
    }

    if (length1 > 1) {   
        s = length / 2; 

        for (i = 0; i < s; i++) {        
            printf("%d\n", sum1[i]);         
        }

        for (i = s; i < length; i++) {        
            printf("%d\n", sum2[i]);        
        }

        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {        
            sum3[i] = sum1[i] + sum2[i];        
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code. It literally makes no sense to look at...

Comment: @DeiDei In the context of https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/ it is appreciated to tell new posters about formatting and indentation after fixing it for them. There is a "try your best, we will help you with the rest" kind of thinking.

Comment: El Khan A decent indentation is really helping with understanding your code and thereby with helping you. Also, it is in your interest to keep potential answerers in as good a mood as possible.

Comment: Can you provide a definition of a kaprekar number? You gave examples, but that is not sufficient for making or understanding an algorithm.

Comment: What is `sizeof(int)` in your environment? If it is 2, then you probably just have a range problem. In that case try using `long int`.

Comment: Please explain why you undid my edits. Do you really think that your question is more likely to get answers in the way you wrote it?

Comment: It seems to me that you are not bringing clarity of thinking to your code. You don't need the length of the square. You need the length of the original number. You don't need to use separate logic for different lengths. I can't post an answer at the moment. I'm waiting to board a plane. I'll post one later if there are no other answers that adequately address the problem.

Comment: Consider an n-digit number k. Square it and add the right n digits to the left n or n-1 digits. If the resultant sum is k, then k is called a Kaprekar number.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add helpful information. Consider rolling back first, to keep my edits.

Comment: I have separated the multiplied digits and stored them in an array.I added those two arrays to bring the given input number.

Comment: You program does not compile (missing declaration of `sum3`), but once that is added, it does print “Kaprekar number” for n=9. https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/fdf26a34 (You should test the result of `scanf`, its result may indicate that it did not read a number, in that case `n` remains uninitialized.)

Comment: For the input `11`, your program invokes undefined behavior by reading from an uninitialized array `sum1`: https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/aa0935e1

Comment: Are you using values of `sum1[i] ` and `sum2[i]` without initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my suggestion to simplify your code, and hopefully make it easier to debug.

1. Define a function that returns the number of digits.
2. Define a function that divides the square into to numbers, given the number of digits in the original number.
3. Compute the sum of the divided parts of the square and compare it with the original number.

---

```
int getNumberOfDigits(int n)
{
   if ( n == 0 )
   {
      return 1;
   }

   int count = 0;
   while ( n / 10 > 0 )
   {
      n /= 10;
      ++count;
   }

   return count;
}

void divideSquare(int square, int originalDigitCount, int out[2])
{
    int left = square;
    int right = 0;
    for ( int = 0; i < originalDigitCount; ++i )
    {
       right  = right*10 + left%10;
       left /= 10;
    }
    out[0] = left;
    out[1] = right;
}

int main()
{
    for (int n = 0; n < 10000; ++n )
    {
       int square = n * n;
       int out[2];
       int count = getNumberOfDigits(n);
       divideSquare(square, count, out);
       if ( out[0] + out[1] == n )
       {
          printf("%d is a Kaprekar number\n", n);
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes with your code, for once you haven't initialized arrays of `sum1` and `sum2` which you use for printing and adding. secondly, array `sum3[]` isn't defined. also if your numbers are more than `2,147,483,647` which means you get an overflow if `a` is more than about 46340.

I was interested in the problem, so here's my implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int get_length(long long n){
    int s = 0;
    while (n>0){
        s++;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return s;
}

int is_kaprekar (long long n){
    long long t, n2=n*n;
    int i,s = get_length(n2);
    t = pow(10,s);
    for (i=0 ; i<s ; i++){
        long long left,right;
        left = n2/t;
        right = n2%t;
        if ((long long)(left+right) == n && left != t){
            printf("%lld\n",n); // print n
            printf("%lld\n",n2); // print n^2
            printf("%lld\n",left); 
            printf("%lld\n",right);
            printf("Kaprekar number\n");
            return 1;
        }
        t/=10;
    }
    printf("not a kaprekar number");
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    long long n,i,n2;
    printf("n ");
    scanf("%d",&n); // get n
    is_kaprekar(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For 297 it has printed as not a kaprekar number but it is actually a kaprekar number.I think something gone wrong with the right_half part.could you please check on this??

Comment: @ElKhan Are you sure you ran this code? it's printing right_half and left_half correctly for me and answers `Kaprekar number`

Comment: @ElKhan by your description in the question I assumed you should split the number in half, but by definition you can split it from anywhere! my previous code didn't work for some above 1000 numbers, the edit fixes it.

Comment: Your program invokes undefined behavior at `printf("%d\n",n2);` because `n2` is a `long long`. It should be `printf("%lld\n",n2);`.

Comment: weirdly it invoked no error in my compiler, thanks I fixed it

Comment: @AlalehA: do you have useful compiler warnings enabled (such as `-Wall -Werror`) ?

Comment: I didn't, Though I fixed that now

Comment: Thanks for your code.but,it  has printed a not kaprekar number for a kaprekar number.but your code gave correct right_half and left_half.could you please check the if statement?

Comment: @Elkhan I changed the code, to be much simpler (try using functions in your code)

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaprekar_number), Kaprekar numbers are defined this way:

> In mathematics, a non-negative integer is called a *Kaprekar number* for a given base if the representation of its square in that base can be split into two parts that add up to the original number, with the proviso that the part formed from the low-order digits of the square must be non-zero, although it is allowed to include leading zeroes. For instance, 45 is a Kaprekar number, because 45<sup>2</sup> = 2025 and 20 + 25 = 45. The number 1 is Kaprekar in every base, because 1<sup>2</sup> = 01 in any base, and 0 + 1 = 1. Kaprekar numbers are named after D. R. Kaprekar.

Your method seems too complicated and broken beyond repair. Here is a simpler approach:

- square the number. I would recommend using a larger type such as `unsigned long long` to avoid arithmetic overflow during this computation.
- iterate in a loop, dividing the square by increasing powers of 10 until the dividend is smaller than 10. If the remainder is non zero and the sum of the quotient and dividend of the square divided by the power of 10 equals the original number, you have a Kaprekar number.

Here is a simple implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int test_kaprekar(unsigned long long n) {
    unsigned long long quo, rem, pow10, square = n * n;
    int i;

    for (i = 1, pow10 = 10;; i++, pow10 *= 10) {
        quo = square / pow10;
        rem = square % pow10;
        if (quo + rem == n && rem != 0) {
            printf("%llu is a Kaprekar number: %llu*%llu = %llu, %llu+%.*llu = %llu\n",
                   n, n, n, square, quo, i, rem, n);
            return 1;
        }
        if (quo < 10)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    unsigned long long i, start = 0, stop = 4294967295, count = 0;
    for (i = start; i <= stop; i++) {
        count += test_kaprekar(i);
    }
    printf("%llu Kaprekar numbers between %llu and %llu\n", count, start, stop);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 is a Kaprekar number: 1*1 = 1, 0+1 = 1
9 is a Kaprekar number: 9*9 = 81, 8+1 = 9
45 is a Kaprekar number: 45*45 = 2025, 20+25 = 45
55 is a Kaprekar number: 55*55 = 3025, 30+25 = 55
99 is a Kaprekar number: 99*99 = 9801, 98+01 = 99
297 is a Kaprekar number: 297*297 = 88209, 88+209 = 297
703 is a Kaprekar number: 703*703 = 494209, 494+209 = 703
999 is a Kaprekar number: 999*999 = 998001, 998+001 = 999
2223 is a Kaprekar number: 2223*2223 = 4941729, 494+1729 = 2223
2728 is a Kaprekar number: 2728*2728 = 7441984, 744+1984 = 2728
4879 is a Kaprekar number: 4879*4879 = 23804641, 238+04641 = 4879
4950 is a Kaprekar number: 4950*4950 = 24502500, 2450+2500 = 4950
5050 is a Kaprekar number: 5050*5050 = 25502500, 2550+2500 = 5050
5292 is a Kaprekar number: 5292*5292 = 28005264, 28+005264 = 5292
7272 is a Kaprekar number: 7272*7272 = 52881984, 5288+1984 = 7272
7777 is a Kaprekar number: 7777*7777 = 60481729, 6048+1729 = 7777
9999 is a Kaprekar number: 9999*9999 = 99980001, 9998+0001 = 9999
17344 is a Kaprekar number: 17344*17344 = 300814336, 3008+14336 = 17344
22222 is a Kaprekar number: 22222*22222 = 493817284, 4938+17284 = 22222
38962 is a Kaprekar number: 38962*38962 = 1518037444, 1518+037444 = 38962
77778 is a Kaprekar number: 77778*77778 = 6049417284, 60494+17284 = 77778
82656 is a Kaprekar number: 82656*82656 = 6832014336, 68320+14336 = 82656
95121 is a Kaprekar number: 95121*95121 = 9048004641, 90480+04641 = 95121
99999 is a Kaprekar number: 99999*99999 = 9999800001, 99998+00001 = 99999
...
86358636 is a Kaprekar number: 86358636*86358636 = 7457814011780496, 74578140+11780496 = 86358636
88888888 is a Kaprekar number: 88888888*88888888 = 7901234409876544, 79012344+09876544 = 88888888
91838088 is a Kaprekar number: 91838088*91838088 = 8434234407495744, 84342344+07495744 = 91838088
94520547 is a Kaprekar number: 94520547*94520547 = 8934133805179209, 89341338+05179209 = 94520547
99999999 is a Kaprekar number: 99999999*99999999 = 9999999800000001, 99999998+00000001 = 99999999
234567901 is a Kaprekar number: 234567901*234567901 = 55022100179545801, 55022100+179545801 = 234567901
243902440 is a Kaprekar number: 243902440*243902440 = 59488400237953600, 5948840+0237953600 = 243902440
332999667 is a Kaprekar number: 332999667*332999667 = 110888778222110889, 110888778+222110889 = 332999667
432432432 is a Kaprekar number: 432432432*432432432 = 186997808245434624, 186997808+245434624 = 432432432
567567568 is a Kaprekar number: 567567568*567567568 = 322132944245434624, 322132944+245434624 = 567567568
665188470 is a Kaprekar number: 665188470*665188470 = 442475700620940900, 44247570+0620940900 = 665188470
667000333 is a Kaprekar number: 667000333*667000333 = 444889444222110889, 444889444+222110889 = 667000333
765432099 is a Kaprekar number: 765432099*765432099 = 585886298179545801, 585886298+179545801 = 765432099
867208672 is a Kaprekar number: 867208672*867208672 = 752050880792003584, 75205088+0792003584 = 867208672
909090909 is a Kaprekar number: 909090909*909090909 = 826446280826446281, 82644628+0826446281 = 909090909
999999999 is a Kaprekar number: 999999999*999999999 = 999999998000000001, 999999998+000000001 = 999999999
1111111111 is a Kaprekar number: 1111111111*1111111111 = 1234567900987654321, 123456790+0987654321 = 1111111111
1776299581 is a Kaprekar number: 1776299581*1776299581 = 3155240201460775561, 315524020+1460775561 = 1776299581
2020202020 is a Kaprekar number: 2020202020*2020202020 = 4081216201612080400, 408121620+1612080400 = 2020202020
2646002646 is a Kaprekar number: 2646002646*2646002646 = 7001330002639001316, 7001330+002639001316 = 2646002646
3846956652 is a Kaprekar number: 3846956652*3846956652 = 14799075482367049104, 1479907548+2367049104 = 3846956652
3888938889 is a Kaprekar number: 3888938889*3888938889 = 15123845682376554321, 1512384568+2376554321 = 3888938889
4090859091 is a Kaprekar number: 4090859091*4090859091 = 16735128102417346281, 1673512810+2417346281 = 4090859091
4132841328 is a Kaprekar number: 4132841328*4132841328 = 17080377442424803584, 1708037744+2424803584 = 4132841328
110 Kaprekar numbers between 0 and 4294967295
```

All powers of 10 minus 1 are Kaprekar numbers in base 10, other Kaprekar numbers are quite rare around log<sub>10</sub>(n) between 10<sup>n</sup> and 10<sup>n+1</sup>.